# docker-compose node app can't reach mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm having a weird connectivity issue with my docker containers.

This is my compose.yaml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  node-app:
    image: "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}"
    container_name: "node-app"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: ./config/.env
    ports:
      - 43332:43332
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: mongo:27017
  mongo:
    container_name: "app-mongo"
    image: mongo:4.0
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
```

So I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline and the first thing it does is to run tests when code is pushed. The pipeline runs this command `docker-compose run --rm app-node npm run test`.

However the it keeps getting the following error.

`MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to mongo:27017 timed out]`

My app is connecting to mongo like this

```
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        mongoose.connection.on('error', error => {
            logMe(error);
            process.exit(1);
        });
```

The weird thing is I can see that the app container itself can talk to the mongo conatiner by its service name ('mongo') at the OS level.

So if I run this - `docker-compose run --rm app-node ping -c 1 mongo`, the ping is successful.

It's running under the following environment

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
```

What could I be doing wrong?? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems like mongo container is not running

Comment: @Adiii it is running and the node app works fine with mongo when I just do `npm start`. it's only when I do it through the ci/cd pipeline and run that exact command.

Comment: Your nodejs app started before the mongo service already. You can search with `wait-for.sh` keyword, and then try.

Comment: Try with `docker-compose up` and the command `npm test` in docker compose file or try with @hoan approach

Comment: I tried both but neither worked. Still getting the same error.